# Is there any way to get both sets of unique weapons the AntAgonizer and Mechanist?

Tags: fallout-3

In Fallout 3 there is a sidequest "The Superhuman Gambit".  You have to make either the AntAgonizer or the Mechanist leave town.  Each of them have a unique weapon and unique armour.

I don't care about completing the quest.  I can get both sets of armour - I just kill each character.  But I would like to get the unique weapon from each character.

Is there anyway of doing this?  Preferably without a mod or a PC-console command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It involves reverse pickpocketing and then killing each one after they give you the weapons.

> This method will get you both the Ant Sting and the Protectron's Gaze,
> as well as both costumes and an extra helmet for each one. This also
> gets you some bad karma, but nothing that can't be easily fixed with
> donations to churches or water beggars. You will need two sets of
> armor with a DR above 12 and two sets of headwear with a DR above 4.
>
> Go to the Mechanist and talk to him. Do not convince him to give up
> his ways or agree to help him. Reverse pickpocket a set of armor and
> headwear on him, then leave and come back. His attire will change and
> you will be able to pickpocket his special armor and helmet.
>
> Go to the Antagonizer and talk to her. Be sure to drop the Mechanist's armor and
> helmet before speaking to her. Do the same thing as before and reverse
> pickpocket the other set of armor and headwear. When she puts it on,
> you will be able to pickpocket her special armor and helmet as well.
>
> Pick up the Mechanist's armor but leave the helmet where it is. Talk
> to the Antagonizer and give her the armor. She will reward you with
> the Ant's Sting. She will leave to wander the wastes. You MUST kill
> the Antagonizer in order to complete the quest at this point. When you
> loot her body, you will find the Mechanist's armor with an extra
> helmet to go along with it.
>
> Go back to the Mechanist with the
> Antagonizer's armor in your inventory. Give him the armor and he will
> reward you with the Protectron's Gaze. Kill the Mechanist and retrieve
> the Antagonizer's armor with an extra helmet.
> -OR- if you want him to live; drop the helmet before you talk to him, then give him the armor and retrieve the Protectron's Gaze, then
> simply pickpocket the armor and extra helmet from him.
> Talk to Uncle Roe at Canterbury Commons to complete the quest.
>
> If you have already have the achievment for the Quest, you can opt to just pickpocket them
> both with the methods above for both reward weapons, armors, and x2
> copies of each helmet. This leaves the quest incomplete, but supplies
> a random encounter for the capitol wasteland with the Antagonizer
> (perhaps the Mechanist as well?) at a later time.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:The_Superhuman_Gambit#Receiving_both_rewards_and_both_costumes